# How to connect to MSSQL-Server using Geoserver?

Tags: geoserver, sql-server, ubuntu

I have Geoserver on Ubuntu 13.04.  On another machine I have MS SQL-Server 2008 R2.  Now I want to connect it together. Google says that its possible to connect to SQL-Server from Ubuntu using ODBC but Geoserver works through JDBC.

In Windows its easy, you just to need to download MS JDBC driver. But what do you do in Ubuntu?

Comment: down load the jar from the Microsoft site and add it to the lib directory.

Comment: @iant: What is lib directory. Im new with Linux. Now i just add jar in CLASSPATH variable in file /etc/environment. Its enough? And what i gonna do next?

Comment: that will probably work - but usually I would look in the GeoServer depoly and add it to WEB-INF/lib with the other jar files (exactly like you would on windows).

Comment: Yeah it was kind of stupid. For connect to SQL-Server gonna make a same like on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Simply download the MS JDBC jar from the [Microsoft site](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/microsoft-jdbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017) and add it to `WEB-INF/lib` in whichever servlet container you are using to run GeoServer.